# GL_OES_vertex_half_float and OES_element_index_uint

Tags: opengl-es-2.0, mali

I've checked through glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS) that my OpenGL ES 2.0 implementations did not support GL_OES_vertex_half_float and OES_element_index_uint. I'm using MALI 400 MP. Are there any way to restore both of them?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to "restore" an extension. If the extension is not included in the string returned by `glGetString(GL_EXTENSIONS)` it means that the **OpenGL ES driver does not support** that particular extension, so the feature is not available.

So on your current device / drivers you're out of luck, I'm afraid.

You could try to request that the driver vendor adds support for these extensions in the future; for Mali, try these [forums](http://malideveloper.arm.com/). But, of course, there may be HW limitations that prevent certain extensions from being supported.